# Count how many low and high guesses

Tags: java

I need to count how many of the guesses are too high and how many are too low.  And then Print these values, along with the total number of guesses, when the user finally guesses correctly.

Could you please show me how to modify my program to do counting of high an low guesses ?

Main code

```
public class Task4t2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean win = false;
        boolean running = true;
        System.out.println("Please enter the upper limit: ");
        Game game = new Game(scan.nextInt());

        while (running) {

            System.out.println("Please enter a guess ");

            while (!win) {
                if (game.guess(scan.nextInt())) {
                    win = true;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again y/n?");
            String playAgain = scan.next();
            if (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                game.reset();
                running = true;
                win = false;
            } else {
                running = false;
                System.out.println("Game over");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

enter code here:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Game {

    private int randomNumber;
    private int tries = 0;
    private int range;

    public Game(int range) {
        this.range = range;
        generateRandomNumber();
    }

    private void generateRandomNumber() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        this.randomNumber = rand.nextInt(range) + 1;
    }

    public boolean guess(int guess) {
        tries++;
        if (guess == randomNumber) {
            if (tries > 1) {
                System.out.println("You got the number in " + tries + " tries.");
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("You got the number in " + tries + " try.");
                return true;
            }
        } else if (guess > randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("Too high try again");
            return false;
        } else if (guess < randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("Too low try again ");
            return false;
        }
        return false;

    }

    public void reset() {
        this.tries = 0;
        generateRandomNumber();

    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you have int tooHigh = 0; and int tooLow = 0; and than in appropriate if statements have tooHigh++, toLow++, and then you can print those wherever you want?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Integer> High = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> Low = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (!win){    //numbers is your array
    int x = scan.nextInt();
    if (game.guess(x))
        win = true;
    else if ( x > desired) //where desired is the random integer
       High.add(x);
    else 
       Low.add(x);
}
for (int x : High)
     System.out.println(x);
for (int x : Low)
     System.out.println(x);
```

You should store the scan if you plan to use it later. To keep the numbers use a dynamic array. You don't know how many numbers the person will guess. I recommend two ArrayList. One to store the numbers that are too high and one to store one for numbers that are too low. You can then print them out with a general for loop or one like I have used below.